# CPU2017 benchmark 510.parest_r build failed with gcc9.3 and gcc9.4

Tags: gcc, benchmarking, arm64, internal-compiler-error

everyone.

I'm try to build CPU2017 intrate and fprate test set on aarch64 server with gcc9.3. All the benchmark build successed, except 510.parest_r. Then i try build it with gcc9.4, meet the same error. I used the Example-gcc-linux-aarch64.cfg as configure file, just edit the gcc path.

Here is the failed info:

```bash
/home/gcc9.3/bin/g++     -std=c++03 -mabi=lp64 -c -o source/me-tomography/synthetic_data.o -DSPEC -DNDEBUG -Iinclude -I. -DSPEC_AUTO_SUPPRESS_OPENMP  -O3         -DSPEC_LP64  source/me-tomography/synthetic_data.cc
/home/gcc9.3/bin/g++     -std=c++03 -mabi=lp64 -c -o source/multigrid/mg_base.o -DSPEC -DNDEBUG -Iinclude -I. -DSPEC_AUTO_SUPPRESS_OPENMP  -O3         -DSPEC_LP64  source/multigrid/mg_base.cc
/home/gcc9.3/bin/g++     -std=c++03 -mabi=lp64 -c -o source/me-tomography/measurements.o -DSPEC -DNDEBUG -Iinclude -I. -DSPEC_AUTO_SUPPRESS_OPENMP  -O3         -DSPEC_LP64  source/me-tomography/measurements.cc
init2.c:52: MPFR assertion failed: p >= 2 && p <= ((mpfr_prec_t)((mpfr_uprec_t)(~(mpfr_uprec_t)0)>>1))
during GIMPLE pass: forwprop
source/me-tomography/measurements.cc: In constructor 'METomography::Measurements::ReferencedMeasurements::RatioMinusRatio<dim, number>::RatioMinusRatio(const libparest::Slave::Stationary::ProblemDescription&, const dealii::Function<dim>&, const std::set<unsigned char>&) [with int dim = 3; number = double]':
source/me-tomography/measurements.cc:1739:7: internal compiler error: Aborted
 1739 |       RatioMinusRatio<dim,number>::
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
0xafbd97 crash_signal
        ../.././gcc/toplev.c:326
0xffff9e304d78 __GI_raise
        ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
0xffff9e2f1aab __GI_abort
        /build/glibc-RIFKjK/glibc-2.31/stdlib/abort.c:79
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
Please include the complete backtrace with any bug report.
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
specmake: *** [/home/spec/cpu2017_aarch64/benchspec/Makefile.defaults:356: source/me-tomography/measurements.o] Error 1
specmake: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

The failed info seem be caused by the MPRF float percision setting?

I tried build 510.parest_r with llvm-10, build success.

By the way, i build same gcc9.3 in x86_64 server, build 510.parest_r success.

Answer (score 1):

You've found a bug in an older version of GCC (or possibly your system's RAM is failing, but unlikely if it consistently crashes at the same place).  Or perhaps a bug in MPFR, although that seems less likely.

If you preprocess that source (add `-E` or `-save-temps` to the command line that crashed) and put it on https://godbolt.org/, does it still crash the same way with *current* ARM64 GCC, e.g. a nightly build of trunk?  (https://godbolt.org/z/K6GnrYrj1 is ARM64 GCC trunk, with your command line args without the preprocessor stuff, which won't matter when compiling CPP output.)

If it still crashes with current GCC, then file a bug report on https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/, ideally with a MCVE of the part of the source that triggers the bug.  (Remove as many parts of the file as you can while preserving the crash behaviour.  e.g. take out tons of stuff, undo if that makes it compile.)

If it doesn't crash with newer GCC, it might already be a known bug, or got fixed by accident, or a different MPFR or other library version mattered.  In that case, maybe not worth reporting it upstream. Or if you do make sure to include the fact that the range of affected versions doesn't include GCC12 or current trunk.  Probably this Stack Overflow Q&A is sufficient for future users to know that it's a known bug.